# jQuery iframe load() event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, iframe

Does anyone know if there is such a thing?

I have a iframe that's being inserted with `$.ajax()` and I want to do some stuff after the contents from the iframe are completely loaded:

```
....
 success: function(html){  // <-- html is the IFRAME (#theiframe)
          $(this).html(html);   // $(this) is the container element
          $(this).show();
          $('#theiframe').load(function(){
             alert('loaded!');
          } 
....
```

it works, but I see the IFRAME is loaded twice (the alert also shows twice).

Comment: Try setting the src of the iframe before appending it to the DOM.  This should prevent the load event from firing twice.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If possible, you'd be better off handling the `load` event within the iframe's document and calling out to a function in the containing document. This has the advantage of working in all browsers and only running once.

In the main document:

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    alert("Iframe loaded!");
}
```

In the iframe document:

```
window.onload = function() {
    parent.iframeLoaded();
}
```

Comment: hey this works! but how can I call a function that's inside the `jQuery(document).ready` function of the parent document?

Comment: @Alex: You'll need to make sure the function is global, which you can do either by declaring it as a variable in the global scope before assigning a value to the variable inside your `ready()` function, or by explictly assigning it as a property of `window` inside your `ready()` function. For example: `$(document).ready(function() { window.iframeLoaded = function() { alert("Load"); }; /* Other stuff here */ })`;

Comment: it seems my double loading problem is me wrapping the iframe between DIV tags. For some weird reason browsers reload the iframe if you do this...

Comment: @Alex: Certainly some browsers reload the iframe document if you hide and show the iframe, or move it around in the DOM.

Comment: i don't understand how its working :( but thanks after all it worked for me >>

  window.onload = function() {
      parent.iframeLoaded();
    }
    function iframeLoaded() {
    }

    var postTempBody = "${postTempBody}";
    /*fill body value*/
    if(postTempBody != ''){
        window.iframeLoaded = function() { 
          var $iframe = jQuery('#tinyMceEditor_ifr');
            alert($iframe.length);
            $iframe.ready(function() {
              $iframe.contents().find("body").append(postTempBody);
          });
        };
    }

Answer (score 84):

use [iframe onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_frame_onload.asp)

```
$('#theiframe').on("load", function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: As of JQuery 1.7 (November 2011), you're supposed to use `$('#theiframe').on("load",function())`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to trigger.

Comment: Don't forget to close with `});` :)

Comment: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jpv03cwf/) that shows that it works.

Answer (score 8):

Along the lines of [Tim Down's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788723/177710) but leveraging `jQuery` (mentioned by the OP) and loosely coupling the containing page and the iframe, you could do the following:

In the iframe:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var w = window;
        if (w.frameElement != null
                && w.frameElement.nodeName === "IFRAME"
                && w.parent.jQuery) {
            w.parent.jQuery(w.parent.document).trigger('iframeready');
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the containing page:

```
<script>
    function myHandler() {
        alert('iframe (almost) loaded');
    }
    $(document).on('iframeready', myHandler);
</script>
```

The iframe fires an event on the (potentially existing) parent window's document - please beware that the parent document needs a jQuery instance of itself for this to work. Then, in the parent window you attach a handler to react to that event.

This solution has the advantage of not breaking when the containing page does not contain the expected load handler. More generally speaking, it shouldn't be the concern of the iframe to know its surrounding environment.

Please note, that we're leveraging the DOM ready event to fire the event - which should be suitable for most use cases. If it's not, simply attach the event trigger line to the window's load event like so:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I refuse to use a cookie to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

That's the same behavior I've seen: iframe's `load()` will fire first on an empty iframe, then the second time when your page is loaded.

Edit: Hmm, interesting. You could increment a counter in your event handler, and a) ignore the first `load` event, or b) ignore any duplicate `load` event.

Comment: if I add `alert($(this).attr('src'));` inside the load function I get the same value twice ...

Answer (score 3):

Without code in iframe + animate:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function resizeIframe(obj) {

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(obj).animate({height: obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'}, 500)

    });

}    
</script>
<iframe width="100%" src="iframe.html" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" >
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be more generic and independent, you can use cookie. Iframe content can set a cookie. With jquery.cookie and a timer (or in this case javascript timer), you can check if the cookie is set each second or so.

```
//token should be a unique random value which is also sent to ifame to get set
iframeLoadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        cookieValue = $.cookie('iframeToken');  
        if (cookieValue == token)
        {
            window.clearInterval(iframeLoadCheckTimer );
            $.cookie('iframeToken', null, {
                expires: 1, 
                path: '/'
         });
        }
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the jquery's [Contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get the content of the iframe.