# Is it possible to emulate an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xhtml

is there a way to get the contents of a page, for example `http://google.com`, and insert it in the current document, but in the way that the iframe does, I mean... with styles, scripts and everything that page has ?

And make so the styles and scripts don't affect the current document :)

Comment: and you don't want to use an iframe because..?

Comment: because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788499/jquery-iframe-load-event :(

Comment: if scripts and styles is built in the page yes you can if its external it will be hard i think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not really: you can get the contents of a page through various AJAX-y techniques, but when you insert them into your page, they'll always have your page's CSS applied to them. You could make some sort of "CSS reset" for the "not-iframe" element, but this will be messy.

Essentially, if you want the separation provided by frames, you need to use frames/iframes (unfortunately, this applies to all content, so  CSS will be separated, but also JS, with all the related cross-domain brouhaha).

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  You can use the object element, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <object data="http://www.google.com" type="text/html"></object>
    <body>
</html>
```

(Works with IE8, Chrome 10, FF 4, and Safari 5 on Win XP)