# Bind to events inside dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, jquery

I need to bind to an event (say a `click` on an arbitrary `<input>`) inside an iframe that is created dynamically after the user performs a certain action. The code that appends the iframe AND the code inside the iframe is not mine and I cannot change it in any way (this is a CMS admin panel).

How can I listen to the events using **jQuery 1.6** (again, this is not my choice, I'm stuck with it). I thought `delegate()` might be what I want:

```
$('body').delegate('iframe input', 'click', function(e) {
    alert('bingo?');
});
```

But the above does not alert when an input is clicked. The below, however, works as expected:

```
$('body').delegate('input', 'click', function(e) {
    alert('bingo?');
});
```

But this is outside the iframe.

The `src` of `iframe` points to the same domain, obviously.

Any help or just a prod in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This `'iframe input'` does not selects `input` elements inside the `iframe`.

You can bind the event like

```
$('body iframe').contents().find('input').bind('click',function(e) {
    alert('bingo?');
 });
```

I think You can also use something like

```
$('body iframe').contents().find('body').delegate('input','click',function(e) {
    alert('bingo?');
 });
```

To detect  if the iframe has been fully loaded, use the method described in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788723/344304

Add In the main/parent document:

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    $('body iframe').contents().find('input').bind('click',function(e) {
        alert('bingo?');
     });
}
```

Add In the iframe document:

```
window.onload = function() {
    parent.iframeLoaded();
}
```

Or use

```
$('body iframe').load(function(){
     $('body iframe').contents().find('input').bind('click',function(e) {
            alert('bingo?');
         });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but `on()` was introduced in 1.7. How can I do it in 1.6?

Comment: Updated code, that should work if you dont have input elements dynamically added to the iframe.

Comment: Thanks. How can I ensure the above `$("body iframe").contents()` is run after the iframe is fully loaded? Or don't I need to make sure?

Comment: Thanks again. Doesn't seem to be working, but I'm not sure why exactly. I'm still investigating.

Comment: I'll assume this works, but it was very tedious to find out why it wouldn't work in my case. I managed to work around the problem by taking a different approach to the problem altogether. Thanks a lot @Joy

Comment: The last one (using load() and contents().find().click()) worked for me, thanks for the idea. Took a while before I realised I had to wait for the document in the iframe to load.

Comment: Great answer thanks. I got it working- but after setting the load callback - I had to actually call load on my iframes.