# Removing attribute from iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is it possible to remove width attribute from an < iframe width="100%" >, with jQuery, either when the DOM is ready or on window.load?

Thanks

Comment: Its been awhile, but windows load event did the trick for me and the answers here dont mention it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788499/jquery-iframe-load-event

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put an ID on your iframe to make it easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myFrame').removeAttr('width');
})
```

Comment: I have a feeling there was no attempt to Google "remove attribute jquery" before asking ... but still good fast answer

Comment: yes I did google and found results, but nothing on my initial find for iframes.  thanks.

Comment: I can appreciate that. An attribute is an attribute. They're not tag-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').removeAttr('width');
});
```

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3rFTF/