# Execute jQuery once document is ready AND iframe content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-masonry

As you can see on this page http://musicglaze.com/chase-status-let-you-go-feat-mali-feed-me-remix/#comments 
comment section is way out of place, After research I understood that it is caused because plugin responsible for styling (http://masonry.desandro.com/) is called within

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

function. however, content is loaded into iframe after that, therefore changing its height, but as plugin takes into account its original height without content everything gets messed up. Is there something I can use which would behave similar to this pseudocode?

```
Document ready AND iframe content loaded {

//My jQuery code

}
```

Comment: Try this if you have access to both the pages

jquery-iframe-load-event


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788499/jquery-iframe-load-event

Comment: Sorry for the off topic but it is a nice looking site http://musicglaze.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same ready() function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frameId').ready(function() {
    ...
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi, didn't seem to fix the issue, Only difference I made to your code was to use all iframes instead one with specific id `$('iframe').ready(function() {` Still, comments section is outof position

Comment: Indeed this does not seem to work. The `.load` answer however works great - that should be the accepted one now.

Answer (score 20):

Use `$('#iframeId').load(function() { ... });` instead of `onReady`. The underlying issue is that there are cross-domain security risks to allowing the parent frame access to an iframe's content, so `onReady` is not available, but `onLoad` is still accessible. For more details, see: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/