# How to set event delegations on iframe load events in jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, event-delegation

In jquery, I want to do this basically:

```
$(window).on('load', 'iframe', function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

Is this possible to do? I want to run a function anytime a iframe is dynamically added to DOM and it finishes loading.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604300/2019247)?

Comment: This is how to set it on the specific iframe, which I already know, but it's different than my question.

Comment: You can try changing `$('#theiframe')` to `$("iframe")`. This should work for all iframes, I guess.

Comment: That works for all *existing* iframes but not new ones added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

When a new iframe is dynamically added to DOM you also have to dynamically create a new event handler function to it. It is the rule and nothing can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe this can be achieved with the combination of `MutationObserver` and jQuery's event bindings.

You can register the observer to the DOM like this (sample code borrowed from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)):

```
$(function() {
  var target = document.querySelector('body');

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // Check if nodes are added
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
          // Check if the added node is an iframe
          if (node.nodeName === "IFRAME") {
            $(node).on("load", function() { alert("hello from iframe"); });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  // configuration of the observer (need to research more on this)
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  };

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(target, config);
});
```

The above will observe the changes in DOM, and will check the added elements to the DOM dynamically.

I believe you can leverage this feature to bind the event on runtime to the added iframes like I did above.

Just don't forget to unobserve after you're done with this:

```
observer.disconnect();
```