# how to set iframe height dynamically depending on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to set the iframe height depending on the content height, here below code is working for local links, but i want to do it on dynamically.
please help.

```
<iframe  id="frameDemo" src="https://myvook.blogspot.com"></iframe>      
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {       
$( "#frameDemo" ).on('load', function() {     
    var mydiv = $(this).contents().find("body");    
    var h = mydiv.height();    
    $("#frameDemo").height(h);    
 });    
});
```

Comment: If the content of the frame is on a separate domain to the parent window, then you cannot access the content through JS, so what you're attempting to do would not be possible.

Comment: Thanks Rory, any other ways to make this happen please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Following up with what Rory said, it's not possible to set the iframe height before before the iframe has been loaded since you'll be pulling content from another domain.

However, it is possible to set the height of the iframe after you've downloaded the content. Here is how I've tackled it:

```
function noteContentIframeLoaded(iframeId) {
  // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5788723 for how to implement this function
  var iframeElement = $("#" + iframeId)[0];
  setTimeout(function() {
    setIframeHeight(iframeElement);
  }, 10);
}

function setIframeHeight(iframe) {
  if (iframe) {
    if (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument) {
      var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
      if (iframeWin.document.body) {
        iframe.height = (iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, could you please tell me how to pass a value (postMessage) to iframe from parent page. I don't have access to iframe container page. I want to pass value and get the response in same page itself, do you have any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean a value? I included a link that shows how to implement this function.

Comment: Content is coming through URL, so I don't have any iframe document or a page. As that link suggest how to pass the onload function to iframe from main document ?

Comment: Hi @Joseph, could you please share any jsfiddle example for this. Above mentioned method is not woriking in my case.